# What is the name for the cap that fits over a camera when no lens is attached

Tags: terminology, body

I have a Nikon D5000 and I was wondering if there is a specific name for a cap that would fit over the front of my camera when no lens is attached.

Answer (score 10):

You want a "body cap".

Specifically the Nikon BF-1A or BF-1B, or a generic equivalent.

http://www.nikonusa.com/en/nikon-products/product/cap-cover/bf-1b-body-cap.html